# Dropbox Api error

Tags: java, android, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to sync a txt file to a file in internal storage on my android app. Right now I'm trying to just read the txt file to logcat to see what happens. It shows the dropbox windows where it asks the permission for this app to "create a folder in your dropbox". When I click allow, nothing happens. The url at the top changes for a bit with a "connect" showing at the end for a while and then it reverts back to the "Allow" screen. please help.

Here's my function to get the txt content to LogCat for now:

```
public void getFromDbx(){

        try {
            mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);

            final String TEST_DATA = " Database does not exist yet";

            final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "data.txt";
            DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath(DbxPath.ROOT, TEST_FILE_NAME);

            // Create DbxFileSystem for synchronized file access.
            DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

            // Print the contents of the root folder.  This will block until we can
            // sync metadata the first time.

            //dont need this code -- ahmed

            // Create a test file only if it doesn't already exist.
            if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) {
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
                try {
                    testFile.writeString(TEST_DATA);
                } finally {
                    testFile.close();
                }

            }

            // Read and print the contents of test file.  Since we're not making
            // any attempt to wait for the latest version, this may print an
            // older cached version.  Use getSyncStatus() and/or a listener to
            // check for a new version.
            if (dbxFs.isFile(testPath)) {
                String resultData;
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);
                try {
                    resultData = testFile.readString();
                } finally {
                    testFile.close();
                }

                Log.i("dbx",resultData);
            } else if (dbxFs.isFolder(testPath)) {

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

My OnCreate:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        //connect dbx to account
                mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);

                //get data from ems_data.txt from dropbox account
                getFromDbx();
```

My OnActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getFromDbx();
            } else {
                Log.i("dbxems", "Link to Dropbox failed or was cancelled.");
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testdatabaseactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >

    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.TestDatabaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <instrumentation
            android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
            android:label="your tests label"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.testdatabaseactivity" />

        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_screen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testdatabaseactivity.SearchByName"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_by_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="db-KEY_HERE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: anyone? i really need help on this one

Comment: You asked the question less than 30 minutes ago, and you're already impatient that you haven't received a response? :-)

Comment: @smarx- yep thats me lol
i havn't created/downloaded the same sync file in internal storage. so unless dropbox api automatically does it that can't be the issue.
even if dropbox api does it, much of this code is taken from the dropbox api sample "hello dropbox" and it works over there, where the code displays it in textview in the android app, but it's just not working over here and i cannot figure out why.